# How to make spectra smooth by using gaussian or lorentzian function

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

I want to use some origin spectrum to fit to my experimental spectra. However, my experimental spectra is not so smooth because of finite resolution of spectrometer. I used to use 'origin' to make it smooth, but it seems not reasonable because I don't know how 'origin' makes it. Then I was suggested using Gaussian or Lorentzian function.
A lot of nonsense, in one word, please teach how to use gaussian or lorentzian function.

Comment: you could fit by hand by adding gaussians or lorentzians to reproduce the spectra. but I think the more numerically justified way of doing it with chi squared fitting or some other type of numerical fitting method.

Comment: It would help us to answer your question if you posted an example spectrum.

Comment: considering that this question was closed, can you consider removing it and posting it on https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com? (generally software based questions are better suited there)

Answer (score 2):

> please teach how to use gaussian or lorentzian function.

It will take several hours of discussion or 4-5 lectures. You are mixing several things.

a) Briefly, your collected spectrum is noisy. You want to remove the noise. What type of spectra is this?

b) The finite resolution of your spectrometer has nothing to do with noise. Increasing the resolution mathematically or so-called deconvolution is another story.

c) The easiest solution is to "fit" Lorentzian or Gaussians to your experimental spectrum after denoising it (step a). Experimental spectra are neither pure Gaussians nor pure Lorentzians.

Here are the steps. I am mentioning the keywords so that you can search the right terms.

0. Can you get hold of PeakFit software? It has a better function library than Origin.
1. Denoise your spectrum, using Savitsky-Golay filter.
2. Once excessive noise has been filtered, use a trial function such as Gaussian or Lorentzian and see which one fits better. This is checked by residuals.
3. In an experimental spectrum, not all peaks have the same width so you will have to use multiple Gaussians or Lorentzians to fit a segment of a spectrum.

Search "*Pragmatic Introduction to Signal Processing Applications in scientific measurement 2019 edition*" by Prof. Tom O'Haver. It is a free book and contains all the practical stuff which would be very useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm grateful for your detailed answer.

Comment: My present condition is that I have gotten the spectrum of several metal solution by using a program which will be used to fit my experimental spectra. I'm sorry I didn't make it clear because I am not familiar with this subject. Anyway, I will follow your advise first. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, your experiment is still not clear. What is type of spectrum and what is the instrument?